# division between integers in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm developing a compiler and I have an issue when I try to generate the assembly code from the following custom language code

```
b:=-2;
c:=-4;
a:=c/b;
```

to test this result I use a if condition asking if a == 2 but is not.

this is the piece  of code generated from the code avobe

```
mov ax, 1
mov _a, ax

mov ax, -2
mov _b, ax

mov ax, -4
mov _c, ax


mov dx, 0
mov ax, _c   
mov bx, _b
cmp bx, 0
JE label_div0Excp  // jump to division by 0 message
idiv bx  
mov @aux0, ax

mov ax, @aux0
mov _a, ax

mov ax, _a
cmp ax,2

JNE label_1

invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr _message0, addr _message0, MB_OK  //_message0 say that result == 2
```

Can enybody help me with that?

thanks

Comment: You're making a 16 bit compiler in this century?

Comment: the compiler only has academic purposes

Comment: @harold: I even intended to do this because I needed one for some kind of boot manager (which of course runs in real mode). It's hardly impossible to find one that is working together with the GNU tool chain (linker). In the end I wrote an incomplete compiler but I wrote the boot manager completely in assembler code so the work for the compiler was useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IDIV` does signed division, so it expects the dividend in `DX:AX` to be a signed doubleword. Instead of clearing `DX` prior to the division you should therefore sign-extend `AX` into `DX:AX`. This can be done with the `CWD` instruction.

From Intel's manual: *"The `CWD` instruction can be used to produce a doubleword dividend from a word before word division."*

Answer (score 5):

The `IDIV BX` instruction does a *signed* divide of `DX:AX` by `BX`. DX:AX is two 16-bit registers glued together and treated as one 32-bit value. You have zeroed DX, but zeroing DX is not sufficient for signed arithmetic. You need to **sign extend** AX into DX. In other words, if `AX` is positive, `DX` should be 0, but if `AX` is negative, then `DX` needs to be -1, aka 0xFFFF. Conveniently, there is an instruction that does this sign extension without explicit compares or jumps:  `CWD` (**c**onvert **w**ord to **d**ouble).

Try this instead:

```
mov ax, _c   
cwd              //  <--------------
mov bx, _b
cmp bx, 0
JE label_div0Excp  // jump to division by 0 message
idiv bx
```